# Understanding STRUCT syntax

Tags: c#, struct

I've inherited some code but am unfamiliar with some things ... namely the syntax of using the brackets before the name of the property as well as the additional name following the property:

```
<fmc_Flight>e__FixedBuffer1 fmc_Flight;
```

What is the purpose of  and then following the property up with once again using fmc_Flight?

```
public <fmc_Flight>e__FixedBuffer1 fmc_Flight;
[FixedBuffer(typeof(char), 5)]
public <fmc_ICAO_arr_arpt>e__FixedBuffer2 fmc_ICAO_arr_arpt;
[FixedBuffer(typeof(char), 5)]
public <fmc_ICAO_dep_arpt>e__FixedBuffer3 fmc_ICAO_dep_arpt;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=20), UnsafeValueType, CompilerGenerated]
public struct <fmc_Flight>e__FixedBuffer1
{
    public char FixedElementField;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=10), CompilerGenerated, UnsafeValueType]
public struct <fmc_ICAO_arr_arpt>e__FixedBuffer2
{
    public char FixedElementField;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=10), UnsafeValueType, CompilerGenerated]
public struct <fmc_ICAO_dep_arpt>e__FixedBuffer3
{
    public char FixedElementField;
}
```

Comment: You're looking at some decompiled code that was generated by the compiler. It uses such names specifically because they're illegal in C# and so will never conflict with any names chosen by programmers

Comment: Nothing except `;` is following the name of the property :)
`<fmc_Flight>e__FixedBuffer1` is the _type_ of the property, and `fmc_Flight` is the _name_ of the property.